# Gitlab CI and php verstion

Tags: php, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have .gitlab-ci.yml. Here we have just composer install. composer.json requires php 7.4.

```
image: php:7.4
stages: # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test

before_script:
  # Install composer dependencies
  - wget https://composer.github.io/installer.sig -O - -q | tr -d '\n' > installer.sig
  - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
  - php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === file_get_contents('installer.sig')) { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
  - php composer-setup.php
  - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php'); unlink('installer.sig');"


unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - php composer.phar install
    - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```

Then I run

```
gitlab-runner exec shell unit_test
```

on my local machine (macos) and get:

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ~7.4 but your php version (7.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Why? Why exactly 7.3.29?
More over, looks like version is ignored for 'image' setting

Comment: Can you grab your CLI and test your Php version ? `php -v`
The error tells you that Composer requires a newer version of php

Comment: Locally installed:  php -v 
PHP 7.4.24 (cli) (built: Oct 12 2021 21:08:53) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.24, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: in terminal check your php version php -v and update php version for terminal.

Comment: I got the same issue and i don't know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your project composer.json :
Find the line "require" which tells your project which version of libraries you need

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
},
```

Edit : if you need 7.4 then you have to write it like this in your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "7.4",
},
```

The solution is not about thre version you use, it's because your project configuration (in composer.json) isn't good

Comment: I need exactly 7.4. And why  will  8.0 fix this issue?

Comment: I edited my answer, please add the require to your composer.json and build your project again